# No Updates for Windows 10

Tags: update, insider-preview

Using my Nokia Lumia 625, I updated to W10 Insider Preview about 3 weeks ago (build number: 10166, Fast Ring).

I am aware that later builds (such as 10512) are available since 10166, but my phone is not finding these newer builds via the Update menu.

I was wondering if there is a reason for this, and whether or not it is a matter of time before I receive an update to a newer build?

Comment: Do you have the Windows Insider app installed?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my Lumia 720. I have downloaded and configured Windows Insider app and then I've got the update.